# IIS 7.5/ASP.NET MVC App - error serving JS

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc

Greetings,

I'm new to working w/ IIS in general, so I hope I'm asking the right question in the right place with the right amount of information. Here goes:

On a Windows 7 64-bit (IIS 7.5) box, I have a ASP.NET MVC application. It works fine on another dev's box that is very similar in configuration. It's setup to use the "Classic .NET App Pool" which in turn is setup to "Enable 32-bit Applications" This is a requirement as we communicate w/ some legacy 32 bit ActiveX controls.

I added the MVC wild card mappings and verified it was set to the .NET v2.xxx 32bit aspnet_isapi.dll.  (The one in Framework, not Framework64).

If I set a breakpoint in the global.asax.cs, I get my breakpoint when running/debugging, but the app is refusing to serve any .js files. When using FireFox w/ Firebug, the Net tab shows 404 Not Found for every requested .js file. All .css are served correctly.

This causes the application to fail, of course. With the exception of the properties set above, IIS is setup "out of the box"

Any ideas/things to try?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a case noob-ness and frustration...

The web.config had and environment setting that was incorrectly set on my machine but never used to point to the JS files. Another dev implemented it and I didn't notice.

Lesson learned (again) is to take a break and approach w/ a fresh mind.

Thanks to all who read this.